# I need help on Strogatz problem 3.5.6 (A model problem about singular limits)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

[Problem3.5.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp8l2.png)
Here is my attempt so far:

a)
\begin{equation}
x = e^{-\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} t} \cosh \beta t +\frac{ e^{-\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} t}}{\sqrt{1-4 \varepsilon }} \sinh \beta t 
\end{equation}
where $ \beta = \frac{\sqrt{1-4\varepsilon}}{2\varepsilon} $.

b) If $\varepsilon << 1$ then
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{1 - 4\varepsilon} \approx 1 - 2\varepsilon\ \ \ \therefore \beta \approx \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon} - 1
\end{equation}
so we get
\begin{equation}
x \approx ( 1 + \varepsilon) e^{-t} - \varepsilon e^{\left( 1 -\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \right) t}.
\end{equation}
But I am not sure what they mean by "two widely separated time scales"...

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. As for the "time scales", consider how $x$ behaves approximately when $t >> 0$ and $t << 0$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your final approximation - I am getting $x\approx(1+\varepsilon)e^{-t}-\varepsilon e^{-\frac1\varepsilon t}$. The two exponentials both start at $1$ and tend to $0$, but at vastly different speeds. When $t\approx s\varepsilon$, the first exponential is very close to $1$ and the second is of constant order, so you have $x\approx 1+\varepsilon-\varepsilon e^{-s}$. On the other hand, if $t$ is of constant order, the second exponential basically vanishes and you are left with $x\approx (1+\varepsilon)e^{-t}$.